# Dynamically setting the pager for subgrids

Tags: java, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery

I have a Grandparent, Parent, Child relationship in a struts2 jquery grid.

My goal is to be able to disable the paging/navigation bar on the Parent grid based off of the number of records returned (dynamically indicating which subgrids get pagers and which don't). The logic for determining the subgrids and retrieving each subgrid is already worked out, however I do not believe it is possible to disable/enable a pager on grids that are already created.

[The wiki](http://trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apager#properties)
shows that the pager is not changeable, and I just wanted to confirm that this behavior is not supported or if I am misinterpreting the information displayed.

What are some other alternatives to accomplish my goal?
I have tried
`jQuery("#grid_Id").jqGrid({pager: false})`
as well as

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
            pgbuttons : false,
            viewrecords : false,
            pgtext : "",
            pginput : false
        });
```

**Code for Grid Creation**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sjg" uri="/struts-jquery-grid-tags" %>

<s:url var="remoteurl" action="updateRPJson"/>
<s:url var="jiJson" action="updateJIJson"/>
<s:url var="shJson" action="updateSHJson"/>
<sjg:grid
    id="gridtable"
    caption="RP"
    dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    pager="true"
    gridModel="RPItems"
    rowList="10,15,20,50"
    rowNum="50"
    rownumbers="true"
    reloadTopics="reloadMyGrid"
    formIds="getRPInstance"
    onSubGridRowExpanded="getJI"
    height="600"
    width="650"
    loadonce="false"
    onCompleteTopics="disableExpandableGrid1"
    onGridCompleteTopics="gridComplete"
    onBeforeTopics="loadBefore"
    errorElementId="gridError"
>
    <sjg:grid
        id="gridtable2"
        caption="JI"
        dataType="json"
        subGridUrl="%{jiJson}"
        pager="true"
        gridModel="jiItems"
        formIds="getJI"
        reloadTopics="getJI"
        rowList="10,15,20,50"
        rowNum="20"
        rownumbers="false"
        onSubGridRowExpanded="getSH"
        autowidth="true"
        loadonce="true"
        onCompleteTopics="disableExpandableGrid2"
    >
        <sjg:grid
            id="gridtable3"
            caption="SH"
            dataType="json"
            subGridUrl="%{shJson}"
            pager="false"
            gridModel="shItems"
            formIds="getSH"
            reloadTopics="getSH"
            rowList="10,15,20,50"
            rowNum="20"
            rownumbers="false"
            autowidth="true"
            loadonce="true"
        >
            <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name" key="true" hidden="true" sortable="false"/>
            <sjg:gridColumn name="health" index="healthIMG" title="" formatter="imageFormatter" width="10"/>
            <sjg:gridColumn name="label" index="label" title="Label" sortable="false"/>
            <sjg:gridColumn name="health" index="health" title="Health" hidden="true" formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
            <sjg:gridColumn name="health" index="healthLabel" title="Status" sortable="false" formatter="healthStatusFormatter"/>
        </sjg:grid>

        <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name" key="true" hidden="true" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="health" index="healthIMG" title="" formatter="imageFormatter" width="10"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="label" index="label" title="Label" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="health" index="health" title="Health" hidden="true" formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="health" index="healthLabel" title="Status" sortable="false" formatter="healthStatusFormatter"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="children" index="children" title="Children" sortable="false" hidden="true"/>
    </sjg:grid>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="name" key="true" index="name" title="Name" hidden="true" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="health" index="healthIMG" title="" formatter="imageFormatter" width="10"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="label" index="label" title="Label" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="health" index="health" title="Health" hidden="true" formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="health" index="healthLabel" title="Status" sortable="false" formatter="healthStatusFormatter"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="children" index="children" title="Children" sortable="false" hidden="true"/>
</sjg:grid>
```

Comment: Before the creation of the subgrid it is possible to disable the pager based on condition - suppose a subGridRowExpanded is used(where the subgrid is created.) Anyway showing the code will help.

Comment: @TonyTomov

The creation of the grids/subgrids is handled via struts jquery grid tags. So the code is pretty basic, but I do not understand how I can utilize this method for creating a subgrid based on a condition, without mixing the JS way of creating jqgrids and the struts grid tag way. Anyways, code for grids is now provided.

How can I utilize struts jq grid tags, with the onSubGridRowExpanded tag and utilizing some JS `$.subscribe` way to set the pager to true or false based on a condition.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with struts. The example with subgrid subgriRowExanded  can be [seen here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/hierarchy/two_level/index.html) and you can get idea how to implement it  in struts-  I hope it is possible to define custom code.